# Getting property [djob] not found on entity [com.xxx.JobsDeviceIds] after upgrading to Spring framework 3.2.2

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am upgrading jdk 11 to jdk 17 and spring framework version to 3.2.2 from 2.7.1 and hibernate-core is 6.4.0.Final
Everything was working fine before this upgrade but now getting below exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.ModelPart.getNavigableRole()" because
> "subPart" is null

When I put breakpoint in `org.hibernate.MappingException`, I found this exception is being thrown internally -  `property [djob] not found on entity [com.xxx.JobsDeviceIds]`

Complete stacktrace:

```
11:49:31.115 [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/xxx/sem/config/SEMConfig.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.ModelPart.getNavigableRole()" because "subPart" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1231) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:949) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753) [spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455) [spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) [spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) [spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) [spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at com.xxx.sem.SemAPIApplication.main(SemAPIApplication.java:15) [classes/:?]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) [spring-boot-devtools-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.ModelPart.getNavigableRole()" because "subPart" is null
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.ModelPart.getNavigableRole()" because "subPart" is null
    at org.hibernate.boot.query.SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor$AttributeFetchDescriptor.resolve(SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor.java:378) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.query.SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor$EntityResultDescriptor.lambda$resolve$0(SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.boot.query.SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor$EntityResultDescriptor.resolve(SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.query.SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor.lambda$resolve$0(SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.boot.query.SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor.resolve(SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.lambda$prepare$3(NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.java:199) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:1065) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.visitNamedResultSetMappingDefinition(MetadataImpl.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.prepare(NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForNamedQueryValidation.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForNamedQueryValidation.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:315) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1507) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    ... 21 more
```

Below are my Entity and IdClass ----

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JOBSDEVICEIDS")
@IdClass(JobsDeviceIdsId.class)
public class JobsDeviceIds implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Integer jobid;

    @Id
    private Integer devicemasterid;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "jobid", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Jobs djob;

    public JobsDeviceIds() {
    }

    public Integer getJobid() {
        return jobid;
    }

    public void setJobid(Integer jobid) {
        this.jobid = jobid;
    }

    public Integer getDevicemasterid() {
        return devicemasterid;
    }

    public void setDevicemasterid(Integer devicemasterid) {
        this.devicemasterid = devicemasterid;
    }

    public Jobs getDjob() {
        return djob;
    }

    public void setDjob(Jobs djob) {
        this.djob = djob;
    }
```

```
@Data
public class JobsDeviceIdsId implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JobsDeviceIdsId() {
    }

    private Integer jobid;

    private Integer devicemasterid;

    public JobsDeviceIdsId(Integer jobid, Integer devicemasterid) {
        super();
        this.jobid = jobid;
        this.devicemasterid = devicemasterid;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: thanks @Jens for your comment, added the stacktrace in the actual question.